# Build Login for semi public access

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, authentication

So I am building a site in salesforce, this site needs to be accessed by a users with a login.  Would it be possible to build a visualforce login page that links to an object where credential details will be stored? would they still need to use a salesforce license?
Just pondering if this can be done by folks more experienced than I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Liability?

I would avoid it, personally. IANAL, but I imagine by storing passwords, you open yourself up to a world of liability you normally don't have to deal with, if you ever get hacked. Currently, liability for hacked credentials ought to fall solely on Salesforce. Consult with your legal team.

## Storage

You obviously don't want to store plaintext passwords on the system. I had heard of it before, but didn't realize **[bcrypt](http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node1.html)** may be available in `Apex` (?). At least, the `Techical Library` recommends that algorithm in an article on **[Storing Sensitive Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets)**, but I am not aware of any published implementations, and implementing the blowfish algorithm appears...non-trivial.

## Encryption Options

If you *do* want to attempt to implement **`bcrypt`** yourself in `Apex`, you might try porting [this project](https://gist.github.com/cavneb/651613) from Java. You could also consider external services like [DailyCred](https://www.dailycred.com/). You could also write an endpoint to do the encryption for you in the language of your choice. Or you if you can run the encryption client side, there are many libraries out there, such as [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs).

## Technical Reference

Anyway, the relevant portion of the aforementioned article:

> ### How Do I Protect My Application?
>
> Consider an application that must authenticate users. We have to store some form of the user’s password in order to authenticate them, i.e. in order to see if the user presented the correct password. We don’t want to store the password in plaintext form (i.e. unobfuscated or unencrypted), because if an attacker is able to recover the database of passwords (such as by using SQL injection or by stealing a backup tape), they would be able to undetectably hijack every user’s account. Therefore, we want to obfuscate the passwords in such a way that we can still authenticate users.
>
> We could encrypt the passwords, but that would require an encryption key — and where would we store that? We would have to store it in the database or in some other place the application can get it, and then we’re pretty much back where we started: An attacker can recover the plaintext of the passwords by stealing the ciphertexts and the decryption key, and decrypting all the ciphertexts.
>   (Most or all database-level encryption schemes fall prey to the “But where is the key?” problem. Note that full-disk encryption, as opposed to encrypting database rows or columns with a key known the database client, is a separate and arguably more tractable problem.)
>
> Therefore, developers have historically used a cryptographic hash function, a one-way function that is (supposedly) computationally infeasible to reverse. They then store the hash output:
>
> ```
> hash = md5    # or SHA1, or Tiger, or SHA512, etc.
> storedPasswordHash = hash(password)
> ```
>
> To authenticate users, the application hashes the provided password and compares it to the stored password:
>
> ```
> authenticated? = hash(password) == storedPasswordHash
> ```
>
> The plaintext password is never stored.
>
> However, there is a problem with this scheme: the attacker can easily [pre-compute the hashes of a large password dictionary](http://www.east.isi.edu/~bschott/pubs/grembowski02comparative.pdf). Then the attacker matches their hashes to those in their stolen database. For all matches, the attacker has effectively reversed the hash. This technique works as well as the password dictionary is good, and there are some very good password dictionaries out there.
>   To address this problem, developers have historically “salted” the hash:
>
> ```
> salt = generateRandomBytes(2)
> storedPasswordHash = salt + hash(salt + password)
> ```
>
> The goal is to make attackers have to compute a much larger dictionary of hashes: they now have to compute 2saltSize (e.g. 216 for a 2-byte salt) hashes for each item in their password dictionary.
>
> However, a salted password hash only makes it more expensive to pre-compute the attack against a large password database. It does not protect from attempts to brute force individual passwords when the hash and salt are known. The only obstacle here is the cost of the computing resources required to perform these calculations, and a single round of MD5 or SHA-1 is no longer expensive enough to slow attackers down. Fast, cheap and highly parallel computation on specialized hardware or commodity compute clusters makes brute force search with a dictionary quite affordable and accessible, even to adversaries with few resources. (See Grembowski, referenced above, and http://lastbit.com/gpu.asp and http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2007/10/russian-crackers-throw-gpu-power-at-passwords.ars.)
>
> Therefore, we need a solution that significantly slows down the attacker but does not slow down our application by too much. Fortunately, it turns out this is easy, and there is code to do it. The canonical solution is [bcrypt by Niels Provos and David Mazières](http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node1.html). The idea is that we tune the hashing function to be pessimal; Provos and Mazières use a modified form of the Blowfish cipher to pessimize its already-slow setup time. Using bcrypt is a fine solution, but it is also easy to build a tunably slow hash function using the standard library of most programming languages.
>
> The benefit of this approach is that it slows down the attacker greatly, but for the application to verify a single password candidate still takes essentially no time. (Additionally, since login actions are such a small fraction of all application traffic, it would still be okay if verification took an entire 0.5 seconds or more.)

Comment: Sure, I think the point is you either need to make a callout or implement your own algorithm natively.